# facebook api get page ratings return Unsupported get request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I already followed instructions from this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/ratings

some config I have already made, this has been run only in facebook graph explorer

- using page_access_token from me/accounts which is a required just want to post this
- the field=open_graph_story and other fields
- age restrictions changed back and forth
- country restrictions changed back and forth

still having the same problem.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Is there something to do with the selected developer only to use this api? I have read something like that in the facebook api but failed to locate the url.

Any details about this problem, please, at least refer me some links.